# Perimeter of a connected subgraph on a square lattice

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose you had a square lattice with periodic boundary conditions $G(V,E)$ where $V$ is the vertex set, $E$ is the edge set. Now suppose we have a spanning subgraph $H(V,E')$, which is made up of 2 connected components $H_{1}(V'_{1},E'_{1})$ and $H_{2}(V'_{2},E'_{2})$ with $abs(\left|V'_{1}\right|-\left|V'_{2}\right|)\leq 1$.  Define perimeter $p$ as

$p=\left|E\right|-\left|E'\right|$.

What is the minimum perimeter of such a subgraph?

In more layman terms, what is the minimum number of edges one has to remove to make 2 connected components of the same size in a square lattice?

I've never taken a course in Graph Theory or Topology so I'm not sure how to start, or even if this is even a difficult problem. If anyone is able to explain a solution or at least point me in the right direction that would be fantastic. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by periodic boundary conditions? Is this a 'torus' made by wrapping a grid around to itself, or just a big square grid?

Comment: Its a torus. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If your 'torus graph' is of the form $C_n \times C_m$ (cartesian product of two cycle graphs, one of length $m$ and one of length $n$), then my guess would be that $p = 2\cdot\min\{m,n\}$, with the best possible cut being one that divides the 'torus' cleanly in half. I'm not sure how I'd go about proving this, but maybe that can be of some help?